# debian - What release critical bugs stop the release?

Tags: debian, bugs

I dont get the meaning of debian release critical bugs at [this page](https://bugs.debian.org/release-critical/).

[image: stretch-rc-bugs]

The above image is timed after stretch-rc2 release. What bugs need to be fixed for a debian stable release to happen?

And what is meant by the lines.
`Total number of release-critical bugs`
`Number that have a patch`
`Number that have a fix prepared and waiting to upload`
`Number that are being ignored`
`Number concerning the current stable release`
`Number concerning the next release`

Answer (score 2):

First, the RC2 release is the [release candidate of the installer](https://www.debian.org/devel/debian-installer/News/2017/20170202), not of the whole release.

Now, each line means the following:

- Total number of release-critical bugs: the total number of bugs filed at levels that are release-critical (serious, grave or critical), in Debian in general (including packages which aren't candidates for the next release)
- Number that have a patch: number of RC bugs which have a patch in the bug tracker
- Number that have a fix prepared and waiting to upload: number of RC bugs which are pending (this is a tag in the bug tracker)
- Number that are being ignored: number of RC bugs which the release team is ignoring (this is also a tag in the bug tracker)
- Number concerning the current stable release: number of [RC bugs which affect packages in the current stable release](https://bugs.debian.org/release-critical/other/stable.html) (Debian 8)
- Number concerning the next release: number of [RC bugs which affect packages in the next stable release](https://bugs.debian.org/release-critical/other/testing.html) (Debian 9, currently "testing")

The number which needs to be as low as possible prior to the release is the last one. It can be lowered by fixing bugs, by ignoring bugs, or by dropping packages from the release.

Comment: Does the total number of rc bugs counted for stable, testing, experimental, sid branches ? What are rc bugs (that too large number of..) for stable release , when its already released ?

Comment: coming late to the party but: Debian bugs have a severity attached to them that can be assessed by formal criteria (e.g. "introduces a security hole that allows access to the accounts of users who use the package"). any severity above a given threshold is considered to be "release critical", which means that for the package to be part of the *next* Debian release these bugs must be handled somehow (as stephen explain). Debian releases are (more or less) immutable, so if an RC-bug is discovered after the release, the package will still be part of that release.